# wordpress admin dashboard is displaying without css

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have first complete wordpress site in my localhost where it was working fine, but when I upload it in server, My admin panel is displaying without css. I have tried to give permission 777 to load-styles.php in wp-admin folder, clear all cache and cookies of browser but issue is still same.
I have attached screenshot of site, any kind of help would be very much helpful.
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the urls to the files in browser tabs?

Comment: @SherKhan: Yes, I have checked it.

Comment: Is console showing 404 error for css files ?

Comment: Yes, it is showing 404 error for css files but all files are there.